Proving a Language is Not Context-Free
How to demonstrate that a specific language is not context-free using pumping lemma?
Hello everyone,
I'm grappling with a theoretical computer science problem and seeking advice or confirmation on my approach. Here's the problem:
Task:
Prove that the language $L = \{a^k b^l c^{k+l} \mid k \geq l \geq 0, k, l \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$ is not context-free.
My Attempt:
I tried to apply the Pumping Lemma for context-free languages to this problem. Assuming $L$ is context-free, there exists a pumping length $p$. Consider the string $s = a^p b^p c^{2p}$, which is clearly in $L$ for $k = l = p$. According to the Pumping Lemma, $s$ can be decomposed into $uvwxy$ with conditions:

For each $i \geq 0$, $uv^iwx^iy \in L$,
$|vwx| \leq p$,
$|vx| \geq 1$.

I hypothesized that any decomposition would lead to a contradiction because the balance between $a$'s, $b$'s, and $c$'s would be disrupted when pumping $v$ and $x$. For instance, if $v$ and $x$ only contain $a$'s or $b$'s, the number of $c$'s won't match when we pump up or down. Conversely, if $v$ and $x$ include $c$'s, increasing or decreasing them while keeping $a$'s and $b$'s constant will also break the required form.
Question:
I am not entirely sure if my interpretation and application of the Pumping Lemma are correct in this context. Does this seem like a valid proof or are there loopholes in my reasoning? Could there be a more straightforward or robust method to show that $L$ is not context-free?
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to solidify this argument or alternative approaches. Thank you!

Your language has the grammar
S -> aSc | T
T -> bTc | epsilon
And is therefore context free. Any “proof” it isn’t is necessarily incorrect.
Ps missed k >= l. Good luck.

The condition $k \ge l$ can easily be dealt with with a simple patch. Assuming it was a homework exercise, let us leave that as an exercise.

My intuition is that no such a patch will work. We have $a^k b^\ell c^{k+\ell}$ with $k\ge \ell$ or equivalently $k=\ell +m$. The resulting language is $a^{\ell+m} b^\ell c^{2\ell+m}$. Three times $\ell$ is not context-free.

Your have the right approach. I'll use the notation $|s|_a$ to denote the number of $a$'s in the string $s$.
From $uv^iwx^iy \in L$ for all $i$, we must have $|vx|_a + |vx|_b = |vx|_c$. You already correctly concluded that the case $|vx|_c = 0$ is impossible.
The other case is $|vx|_c > 0$. From $|vwx| \leq p$, we have $|vx|_a = 0$ ($vwx$ cannot include the substring $ab^pc$ of length $p+2$).
Then, $|vx|_a = 0$ and $|vx|_b > 0$ therefore we have $|uv^2wx^2y|_a < |uv^2wx^2y|_b$ and we have violated the condition $k \geq l$ in the definition of $L$. Note that if that condition is not in the definition of $L$ then the language is context-free.
To be pedantic, corresponding line in the your proof "increasing or decreasing them while keeping a's and b's constant will also break the required form." might be ambiguous because we don't violate the condition in the case of $v=b^n$, $x = c^n$ for some $n$, and $i = 0$.
